# ajax giving html and script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

(this is is the context of the [melt-monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor) -a free GPLv3 software on which I am working which should later be connected to [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/))

Let's suppose I have an Ajax request whose response makes a new JqueryUI [tab](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to be added to some existing tab-panel.

My Ajax response would obviously return some HTML snippet for that new tab content:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, ....</p>
</div>
```

It should also carry some HTML snippet for the list item giving the title of that tab:

```
 <li id='titletab-1'><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
```

And it should obviously carry some Javascript code invocation to glue the tab title, the tab content into the existing tab-panel.

```
  <script>add_new_tab('titletab-1','tabs-1')</script>
```

currently, the response I am sending is a catenation of the tab content HTML, the list item HTML, and the script element. However, that makes the `<script>` element a part of the DOM, which I feel is a useless payload. (I believe the browser should just execute once that script and throw it away). That also makes the reply incorrect HTML (since the `<li>` element is not inside an `<ul>` even if the `add_new_tab` function would put that `<li>` inside the appropriate `<ul>`)

Is there some better approach? I was considering replying some JSON data containing the text of all three above, but I find that a bit heavy also....

Comment: All script tags are like that, they're executed just once. But they still stick around in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JSON in the form:

```
{ html: "<div>...</div><li>...</li>",
  code: "add_new_tab(...)" }
```

Then your AJAX callback can be something like:

```
function(response) {
    $("#wherever").html(response.html);
    eval(response.code);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be better something like a `{html_for_div: "<div>...</div>"; html_for_li:"<li>...</li>"; code: "add_new_tab(...)"}` ? Also, I was thinking that using `eval` is generally bad manners...

Comment: Perhaps. But the way you described the current behavior, I assumed everything was returned as one big block of HTML. So I thought the only thing that needed to be split out was the JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can reply with the tab content and generate the other codes.

Replay like this:

```
<div id="tabs-1" tab-title="Nunc tincidunt" tab-id="titletab-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, ....</p>
</div>
```

Then parse the HTML code (maybe in jQuery)

```
var content = $(
    '<div id="tabs-1" tab-title="Nunc tincidunt" tab-id="tabs-1">' +
        '<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, ....</p>' +
    '</div>'
);
var title = $('<li></li>').attr('id', content.attr('tab-id'));
content.removeAttr('tab-id');
$('<a></a>').attr('href', "#" + content.attr('id')).appendTo(title);

title.appendTo(document.body);
content.appendTo(document.body);

window.add_new_tab(title.attr('id'),content.attr('id'));
```

---

**Edit**

@Barmar's answer is a better solution (formating data in json)
[ajax giving html and script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051984/ajax-giving-html-and-script/24052059#24052059)
, but avoid using `eval` function. Its better to return an action name for example, and based on this name execute a precoded action.

Comment: Thanks. That was my original solution. But I had to put a `<script>` in the ajax HTML response. Beside, this does not really permit to have some structured `<span>` HTML in the title.